# How can I choose which duplicate rows to be dropped?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to merge a new dataset in with an old dataset, I have a Seq[String] of primary keys for each table type, and an old dataframe and a new dataframe with the same schema.

If the primary key column values match, I want to replace the row in the old dataframe with the row in the new dataframe, if they don't match, I want to add the row in.

I have this so far:

```
    val finalFrame: DataFrame = oldDF.withColumn("old/new",lit("1"))
        .union(newDF.withColumn("old/new",lit("2")))
        .dropDuplicates(primaryKeySet)
```

I add a literal column of 1's and 2's to keep track of which rows are which, union them together, and drop the duplicates based on the Seq[String] of primary key column names. The problem with this solution is that it doesn't let me specify which duplicates are dropped from the table, if I could specify that duplicates with "1" are dropped that would be optimal, but I'm open to alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pounded my head on it a little longer and figured out a trick.  My primary keys were a sequence, and so couldn't be straight taken into a partitionBy in a window function, so I did this:

```
  val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(primaryKeySet.head, primaryKeySet.tail: _*).orderBy(desc("old/new"))
  val duplicateFreeFinalDF = finalFrame.withColumn("rownum", row_number.over(windowFunction)).where("rownum = 1").drop("rownum").drop("old/new")
```

Essentially just used vararg expansion so partitionBy would take my list, and then a rownum window function so I could make sure to get the most recent copy in case of a duplicate.